# What is the name for this connector socket pin configuration?

Tags: identification, connector, socket, vintage

Does anyone recognize this female socket pin layout as a standard design of any kind?

I was looking at 5-pin CB Radio Microphone sockets, and they are similar, but not the same layout.

Also, the ones I saw did not have the "sixth" connector pin in the middle hole. Does that make this a 6 pin socket?

If it helps, these are vintage sockets most likely 1980s or earlier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like it *might* be a DIN connector. The thing with DINs is that they are often offered in varying circular arrangements of the pins - this might be a variant of the 240deg 5-pin DIN.  I cannot locate one with that large center pin ( is it a chassis ground?)

Comment: looks like a std DIN-5 for MIDI but has +1

Comment: looks like some sort ofvariant of 240-degree 6 pin DIN with pin 6 replaced with some sort of coaxial connector  also these seems for be some sort of added locking lugs or thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bog-standard DIN connector. The thing in the middle is a rivet, not a pin. I suggest replacing it with something saner though. Any modern circular connector would perform better. Those DIN connector had one benefit: cheap and fairly low precision needed to make them, compared even to the venerable D-Sub connectors. Outside of extremely cost constrained consumer applications, I wouldn't use one. Much better connectors don't cost all that much more.

Answer (score 8):

It's a 5-pin microphone connector.

[image]

There is no central pin. That's a chassis-ground lug in the centre,  attached to the connector body, to which the shields are to be connected.

[image]

They are still being manufactured.

Please search for '61HA5FX Connector'.

Comment: Do you recognize the brand logo on the back? in your first pic

Comment: Hi pyridoxal_trigeminus, It's not that legible but it appears like 'Prem' in a floral script.